# Thymeleaf HTML page forward problem to External Website in Spring Boot App

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've created a Spring Boot App, in which I am fetching data from external API, store them in database and then displaying them back at front-end in HTML using Thymeleaf. Everything works perfectly fine except one thing.

One of the columns in db, has the name "HEADLINE" which is mapped as String variable and contains news headlines. I am using this column values as texted hyperlinks in my Spring Boot app combined with URLs stored in the same database ("news_link" column), to redirect to the source of them. Below I am showing my front-end code.

**Front-End Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Spring Boot Thymeleaf Hello World Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles/db.css}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>

</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://github.com/Andreas-Kreouzos">Github</a></li>
</ul>

<main role="main" class="container">

    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>IoT Application</h1>
    </div>

</main>
    <!--Display DB contents on HTML and Thymeleaf-->
    <div class="container text-center" id="tasksDiv">
        <h3>Database Contents</h3>
        <hr>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>news_id</th>
                    <th>news_provider_name</th>
                    <th>HEADLINE</th>
                    <th>news_link</th>
                    <th>related_image</th>
                    <th>Timestamp</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="rate: ${rates}">
                        <td th:text="${rate.news_id}"> </td>
                        <td th:text="${rate.news_provider_name}"> </td>
                        <td th:text="${rate.HEADLINE}"> </td>
                        <td> <a th:href="${rate.news_link}"> <p th:text="${rate.HEADLINE}"> </a> </td>
                        <td> <img th:src="${rate.related_image}" alt="error displaying image"> </td>
                        <td th:text="${rate.timestamp}"> </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

When I am running my application everything displays just fine, but as soon as I press the texted hyperlinks, I am redirected at the home page instead of the given URLs which I've stored in my DB. Below, I am showing you my printscreen in which you can definitely see that URLs have been fetched and assigned properly, when I am hovering my cursor above them in my browser, just before I press them. But as soon as they do get pressed, I am getting redirection [here](https://www.investing.com/), instead of
[here](https://www.investing.com/news/cryptocurrency-news/tether-liquidates-celsius-position-with-no-losses-to-stablecoin-issuer-2845626).

Any ideas about what am I doing wrong?

[image: Browser View]

**UPDATE**

I tried to change the `th:href="${rate.news_link}` to `th:href="@{${rate.news_link}}` but still nothing works. If, for example, my initial URL is

```
https://www.investing.com/news/cryptocurrency-news/tether-liquidates-celsius-position-with-no-losses-to-stablecoin-issuer-2845626
```

gets chopped off to `https://www.investing.com/`

**UPDATE 2**

I created the following controller but I am getting null URL -> `http://localhost:8080/null`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView method(
            @RequestParam(name = "news_link", required = false) String news_link) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + news_link);
    }
```

Comment: Any help would be useful!

Comment: While u have the link, can you copy URL by right click on the table?
We need to investigate if the URL is created correctly? or it's corrupted.

Comment: @AshishRatan yes, if I right click and copy the URL, then I can paste it in my broswer and opens up the URL correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a controller with 2 methods :

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World!");

       //I have set below manually just for demo, but in real code, you can fetch this details from database & then set.      
        model.addAttribute("news_linkvalue", "https://www.investing.com/news/cryptocurrency-news/tether-liquidates-celsius-position-with-no-losses-to-stablecoin-issuer-2845626");
        
        return "helloworld";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView method(@RequestParam(name = "news_link", required = false) String news_link) {
         
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + news_link);
    }
```

And then in `helloworld.html` I have used below anchor tag:

```
<p><a th:href="@{/redirect(news_link=${news_linkvalue})}">Click here</a></p>
```

After starting spring boot with `http://localhost:8080/hello` when I click on `Click here` option, it is  going to home page of https://www.investing.com/  and giving `HTTP 301` response while I clicked on link.

This behaviour be viewed by clicking `network`-> clicking on first record->`Headers` section.

This mostly means, site is blocking any cross origin unsecure requests (i.e. requests originated from a domain having `http` protocol ) to their specific pages other than home pages.

If you use any online javascript editor or stackoverflow editor, use same anchor tag for specific page, it will load because request is coming from secure origin (https), example is as below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p>Checking Cross origin requests </p>
<p><a href="https://www.investing.com/news/cryptocurrency-news/tether-liquidates-celsius-position-with-no-losses-to-stablecoin-issuer-2845626">Click</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This mostly means, This site's specific pages(other than home page) will only be accessible if and only if protocol security level is same (i.e. HTTPS) while accessing specific page.

Local spring boot uses default `http` protocol & that is reason when we access specific page of this website,  we always redirects to main page.

How you can fix:

1. Check if you can run your local spring boot code with `https` (i.e. by enabling ssl with either one-way auth or mutual auth). You can find few sample examples online of using spring boot with secure http.
2. You can deploy your application to any secure application server or any cloud environment based on availability & check if running application over non-local environments  fix this issue. Your application url must be accessible via `https` here.

Comment: I tried to do the following 1. Changed my Thymeleaf as you proposed to `<td><a th:href="@{/getLink}"> <p th:text="${rate.HEADLINE}"></a></td>`. 2. Created a controller which can be shown above in my initial edited post. I am getting null URL -> http://localhost:8080/null

Comment: By the way, any reason in your controller you are passing request param?  based on your question, I don't think you need request param.

Comment: What I think is when you click on anchor tag while using spring & thymeleaf, spring always goes to root / home url instead of going to actual url. So that is reason I proposed  to create local resource which will then  redirect you to actual url. Also, let me check why you are getting null

Comment: I am trying to pass my URL's from Thymeleaf back to controller and access them from there by returning a redirection to them. Should I use @PathVariable instead? I forgot to mention that I am new to Spring.

Comment: I am thinking you should use empty get web service which will share you your actual url. but let me reread your requirement if I miss anything,

Comment: Just for your efforts please accept the bounty points.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot !! I am honored

Comment: I will try to implement your solution and search more. Hope I will solve this.

Comment: I am also implementing a sample example for you in meantime, will see how I can tackle this issue

Comment: @Alex_Pap ,I have shared root cause along with what I have tried for this issue. Will try to provide solution soon.

Comment: @Alex_Pap : I have updated my answer ; please have a look & let me know thanks

Comment: Don't know how to thank you enough. There's was not any possibility thinking of that. Btw, I started learning Spring Security in order to implement it in my app. So I think I will be lucky enough to come across such issue. I will search for it and I am considering this question as completed!!! Thank you once again!!!

Comment: @Alex_Pap, no worries thanks a lot, I too learned a lot with this question.

Comment: I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBEq0Kv7vsw) guide and I implemented the self-signed certificate. My app runs on https but still the redirections don't work. I will create another question based on that in the near future. Thank you again!

Comment: Yeah, just make sure, when you use `https`, it is not showing you  `unsecure` alert when you hit your application. I too tried it with my own `https://localhost:8443/hello` request, but it won't work because it was showing me `unsecure` alert in browser.

Comment: Moreover, there might be case that `investing.com` might be blocking `cors (cross origin resource sharing)` request which has domain name containing `localhost` , we don't know.

Comment: If your project allows, consider deploying this boot app to any cloud container / docker & see if it still don't work.

Comment: I tried using some other similar websites e.g. `moneycontrol.com/..` , & it worked, even some more popular websites like `bbc.com/..` & it too worked well without giving home page option.

Comment: So that drives my conclusion that , localhost with http protocol might be blocked by `investing.com`.

Comment: Just another tip : `investing.com` has quite  a lot of restriction it looks like. I have used `curl -v https://www.investing.com/news/cryptocurrency-news/tether-liquidates-celsius-position-with-no-losses-to-stablecoin-issuer-2845626`  from my mac machine. My domain is United Kingdom, & I can see curl is giving `HTTP 403` forbidden request. 

Even you can't access `curl -v https://www.investing.com`, it will also gives `HTTP 403`. So this means, you can't even access this site other than from browser it looks.

Comment: @Alex_Pap, just in case if you find any other observation, please let me know, would keen to know if you find anything other than what I have observed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a dynamic link, so it seems correct to me how you set up the code in the page:

```
<a th:href="${link}">Link</a>
```

Rather check what the controller is giving you back, it should be something like this:

```
return new ModelAndView("page").addObject("link", <link>)
```

If in doubt, try to put the complete link to the entire field as proof:

```
<td> <a th:href="http://www.test.com"> <p th:text="${rate.HEADLINE}"> </a> </td>
```

edit: I didn't understand your "UPDATE 2" ... you have to read on a list of objects, so the controller will have to return the list object to the page. You don't need to do the opposite if you don't alter this data, so nothing has to go back to the controller from the page.

Comment: Thank you for answer @Fede Ota. The "page" refers to the HTML file, I've created or to the destination URL? My HTML file shows a list of URLs at the runtime of my application which somehow need to be passed in the controller.

Comment: The controller must know where to put your object (a list), for this in the page you must have a component that contains the th: object.  I mentioned generic page because in this case it was simple, but it could be more detailed as a form, example:
<form action="#" th:action="@{/...............}" th:object="${form}"
and controller side you will have:
model.addAttribute("form", rates);
so that the list 'rates' is recognized. 
This way is just an alternative, I guess you (controller side) directly returned your list like this:
List<String> urls = ..... ;
model.addAttribute("rates", urls);

Comment: At this point, let's try them all :D
it seems to me that some versions of Tymelea give problems with "_" in the names (or in any case not using the official syntax). Change your variables with:

news_id -> newsId
news_provider_name -> newsProviderName
HEADLINE -> headline
news_link -> newsLink
related_image -> relateImage

and you see what happens.

Comment: I tried somehow to implement a form to see if there's any window of opportunity for my URLs to be grabbed automatically and send them back to controller. Unfortunatelly nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your thymeleaf is correct. You can check the resulting html with your browser's dev tools, in `elements` tab. You should also check the ongoing requests under the `network` tab.

The server is redirecting you to the home page after accessing an article. I doubt anyone say why, this is server side logic. It may be best to get in contact with the owners about the issue.